# Create an option to be modified by options() in an R package

Tags: r, r-package

I am making an R package with functions that should output different things, ideally depending on the setting of an option with `options(myoption = ...)`.

For example, if `myoption`, set by the user at the beginning of their session, can either be `TRUE` or `FALSE` (let it be `FALSE` by default), one of the package's functions may read:

```
if (myoption) {
    # use method A
} else {
    # use method B
}
```

**Q:** How are you able to build this functionality into an R package?

I have come across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663790/standard-mechanism-to-have-package-specific-options) which seems to be what I'm looking for, but the accepted answer isn't detailed enough for me to be able to  use. Quite possibly, this answer betrays my lack of understanding of how `options()` works internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is obvious in hindsight but posting it here in case anyone learning to develop R packages has the same question in the future.

---

To implement what I wanted, my function definitions included something like:

```
...

if (!getOption("myoption", default = FALSE)) {
 # use method A, will be used if myoption is not set by the user (i.e. the default)
} else {
 # use method B
}
```

Once a user calls `options(list(myoption = TRUE))`, the function will use method B.